# OcTree is Null after dynamic_cast from AbstractOcTree

Tags: ros, octomap, ros-kinetic, octree, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I am trying to read an `Octomap` published by `/octomap_full` as `octomap_msgs::Octomap` type. My requirement is reading nodes of the octree and do further operations on the data. I have the following `cpp` function as explained in every documentation and source.

```
void octomap_callback(const octomap_msgs::Octomap::ConstPtr& msg){
   ROS_INFO("Octomap resolution: [%f]", msg->resolution); 
   AbstractOcTree* tree = octomap_msgs::msgToMap(*msg); 
   OcTree* octree = dynamic_cast<OcTree*>(tree);
   ROS_INFO("Resolution of octree: [%f]" , octree->getResolution()); 
}
```

The program is compiled normally without any warning. But when I run it I get the following result.

```
[ INFO] [1558769545.208112901]: Octomap resolution: [0.020000]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As I checked with the condition: `if(octree){ },` the octree seem to be `NULL`.

What am I doing wrong here?

How can I `dynamic_cast` the `AbstractOcTree` to `OcTree` correctly?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323989/octree-is-null-after-dynamic_cast-from-abstractoctree/) by [TharushiDeSilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/40232/tharushidesilva/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2019-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As stated in the octomap_msgs reference (http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/octomap_msgs/html/namespaceoctomap__msgs.html#aebd9cf5ae6b6741b05e9f8dee383f410)  , you have to free the memory after its use.

```
delete octree;
```

---

Edit:

In more details:

Simple Solution (not recommended if octomap is publishing map messages at some frequency) to get the idea across

```
void octomap_callback(const octomap_msgs::Octomap::ConstPtr& msg){
   ROS_INFO("Octomap resolution: [%f]", msg->resolution); 
   AbstractOcTree* tree = octomap_msgs::msgToMap(*msg); 
   OcTree* octree = dynamic_cast<OcTree*>(tree);
   ROS_INFO("Resolution of octree: [%f]" , octree->getResolution()); 
   // do some processing with octree
   delete octree;
}
```

To re-iterate the point about freeing the memory of each created octomap object, not just at the end of the program, please have look at the following code snippet.

Usual solution

```
ColorOcTree* octree = NULL;  // your global or class wide variable
std::mutex mutex_;    // a mutex to resolve the race conditions. 

void octomap_callback(const octomap_msgs::Octomap::ConstPtr& msg){
        octomap_msgs::Octomap received_msg = *msg; 
        AbstractOcTree* tree = octomap_msgs::fullMsgToMap(received_msg); 
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_); // lock the mutex
        if( octree != NULL )  // in-case we are receiving a new octomap before we processed the last one
            delete octree;      // so delete the previous stored object
        octree = dynamic_cast<OcTree*>(tree);
}    


void process_octree(){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_); // lock the mutex
    // process the octree_
    // then delete it
    delete octree_;
    octree_ = NULL;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Namal Senarathne](https://answers.ros.org/users/3870/namal-senarathne/) with karma: 246 on 2019-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TharushiDeSilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/40232/tharushidesilva/) on 2019-05-27**:
@Namal Senarathne,
`delete octree;` gave me the same result.

I declared the AbstractOctree, and Octree as global variables, and assigned the values like the following.

```
AbstractOcTree* tree;
ColorOcTree* octree; 
void octomap_callback(const octomap_msgs::Octomap::ConstPtr& msg){
        octomap_msgs::Octomap received_msg = *msg; 
        tree = octomap_msgs::fullMsgToMap(received_msg); 
        octree = dynamic_cast<OcTree*>(tree);
}
```

And at the end I cleared the nodes from the octrees like this;

```
tree->clear(); 
octree->clear();
```

**Comment by [Namal Senarathne](https://answers.ros.org/users/3870/namal-senarathne/) on 2019-05-27**:
clear() function is used to clear the internal tree data structure of the octree object. Not to free up the memory used by the entire object. I've edited my answer with more details. Hope this helps.

**Comment by [hesham](https://answers.ros.org/users/76126/hesham/) on 2022-12-15**:
I actually tried your snippet and it is semantically wrong. If your try it you get

`error: cannot convert ‘octomap::OcTree*’ to ‘octomap::ColorOcTree*’ in assignment 125 |         color_octree = dynamic_cast<octomap::OcTree*>(msg_octree);  // dynamic casting from octomap::AbstractOcTree to octomap::OcTree |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ |                        | |                        octomap::OcTree*`